# Use the :g command in vim with multiple actions

Tags: regex, vim, command, macvim, text-processing

How can I use something like this?

```
:g/^$/kJ
```

Here kJ are two commands, instead of just one (like 'd')

My concrete example: I have multiple lines looking like this

```
queryBuilder
    .append("xyz");
```

and I want to make them look like this:

```
queryBuilder.append("xyz");
```

So what I want to do for each line is

```
:g/^[\t]*\..*$/kJx
```

which matches the correct pattern but seems to execute only k.

Are other vim commands suitable here? How would you perform this task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `normal` instruction to execute all of them, like:

```
:g/^[\t]*\..*$/normal kJx
```

Comment: awesome! exactly what I needed! what does 'normal' actually do?

Comment: @ka2011r: `:g` lets you run `ex` commands (which begin with colon), `:normal` is an `ex` command that lets you execute Normal commands, those that you wanted, `k`, `J` and `x`.